# Oddity with templates and root node with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I think this is possibly a bug I've stumbled across, not sure. I'm getting this Vue.js warning for a component:

> vue.js:2611 [Vue warn]: Cannot use `<template>` as component root element because it may contain multiple nodes:

The problem seems to be this:

```
<template id="tpl-field">
    <template v-if="fieldType==='checkbox-inline'">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">[SNIP]</label>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
    [SNIP]
    </template>
</template>
```

So I have two template nodes, which seems to be the multiple nodes it's choking on (certainly each of the template nodes contains just a single node). Yet this is an if-else in Vue - if one of the nodes is present, the other logically cannot be.

Demo of the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonmor51/Ldz3k0jp/1/. If I wrap everything in a div, it works. But without, it fails. (Unfortunately, in the context where I want to use this, namely for inline checkboxes within a Bootstrap grid, wrapping in a div breaks things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner `template`s direct children, are they single elements? If so, you can just remove the inner `template`s and move `v-if` to the `label`.

Or, just use `span` rather than `div` as your quick fix, which won't break inline elements' style.

Comment: You're right, and that's interesting. If I move the v-if and v-else to the contained elements, there's no problem, even though superficially the same situation is present (i.e., two alternative root elements, this time divs not templates). So it seems it's just templates which cause the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/jonmor51/Ldz3k0jp/3/

Comment: @JohnMoore I actually didn't try it out when I suggested removing the `template`s... So it turns out vue can correctly tell whether there'll be one root element when `v-if` is used. And `template` is just not allowed as root, vue go straight and gave the warning without analyzing what'll be finally rendered.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will solve your problem with bootstrap... but you could wrap you inner templates with a `<transition>` tag and set a key to each one.

Please check this working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/AldoRomo88/7c7znu3p/

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the job nicely. It does it without 'key' as well, so why is 'key' necessary? I may go with this even though it has the feel of a bit of a kludge (it's not what transition is for), but it moves me on at least!

Comment: I am getting warning however that transition cannot work with lists. ;-) In my opinion vue.js developers messed something up properly.

Comment: @Drachenfels am sure its because you wanted to render multiple dom elements, inside transition tag at the same time. After applying conditions of v-if else etc. there must be only one element to render or you need to use transition-group which wraps elements in additional tag. Btw it's so annoying: i had problem with it, after few minutes i thought about using transtition tag, then next problem occured and i accidentaly found solution to previous task :|

Answer (score 5):

helpful thing - just use **div display: contents** as a root of the component and browser will ignore that element and consider child elements (which can be many) as children of upper dom element

```
    <div style="display: contents">
        <template v-if="...">
            <template v-for="..."> ...
        </template>
        <template v-if="...">
        </template>
    </div
```

works even inside tables!