# Vue & conditional rendering with template tag

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, web-frontend

I am trying to follow documentation:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

But for some reason my template is not working as expected, as soon as I put `<template v-if="variable">` vue fails to render anything.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="dashboard-inititial-message">

<template v-if="okBoom">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</template>

<div v-if="ok">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <p>ELSE</p>
</div>
</script>
```

Any advice?

Snippets that demonstrate problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2tL2ems/1/

Comment: I get a warning`[Vue warn]: Cannot use <template> as component root element because it may contain multiple nodes`. Maybe try wrapping the template element in a div.

Comment: I wonder, I did not receive any warning in my console, is it something that has to be turned on and if so: How? I am using vue in simplest way possible, in a browser.

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought the warnings were shown by default. It seems you can turn them off with `Vue.config.devtools = false;`

Comment: Yup got it, tank you sir. You helped me a lot. :-) I was using production vue (min.js) instead of dev one (non-minified). Once I swapped them I have juicy warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thing to know about vue.js, Peter pointed it out in a comment. Template cannot be a root element and in general root tag can be only one.

So when you have template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="dashboard-inititial-message-mk1">
    <div v-if="okBoom">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
    <h3>adas</h3>
    <div v-if="ok">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

You basically asking vue.js for problems. Vue will stop parsing your template as soon as div with okBoom ends.

There are questions similar to mine all over the internet:

- [Oddity with templates and root node with vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939251/oddity-with-templates-and-root-node-with-vue-js)

Solution in short. Wrap your template into master span, div or transition (this one however seems to be a bit hacky, on the other hand it won't generate unnecessary html tags).

Answer (score 0):

I use conditional template rendering for loaders (while a server request is taking place)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template:
  `<div v-else class='somePage'>
       <template v-if="isLoading">
         <div>LOADING...</div>
       </template>
       <template v-else>
         <h1>title</h1>
         <p>The final rendered result will not include the "template" element.</p>
       </template>
    </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    isLoading: true
  }),
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(this.getData.bind(this), 1500);
  },
  methods: {
  async getData() {
      // await axios ...do some request...
      this.isLoading = false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```