# Vue: Display Loader when request is in progress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I want to implement a process as below:

When a http request is in progress, display a loader. When the requests finish hide the loader.

Comment: Here is an implementation similar to what  you want to do https://jsfiddle.net/adamwathan/xov6ksvd/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481352/104380

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I assume that you want to show a loader when a http request is on progress.

```
<template>

    <div>

        <div v-if="loading">
            <!-- here put a spinner or whatever you want to indicate that a request is in progress -->
        </div>

        <div v-else>
            <!-- request finished -->
        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data: () => {
          loading: false
        },

        methods: {
          makeRequest () {
            this.loading = true //the loading begin
            axios.get('/example')
            .then(response => { ... }) // code to run on success
            .catch(error => { ... }) // code to run on error
            .finally(() => (this.loading = false)) // set loading to false when request finish
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Note that I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) in the example, but the logic works with other htpp libraries or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)*

Comment: The problem with this occurs if you have more than one request running at the same time as this will hide the loader when it is finished even if the other request has not yet 
 completed.

Answer (score -1):

**Only for Nuxt.js users**

the example that roli wrote up is great, but ideally **you don't want to repeat yourself** on every request that you make. so I would suggest you do like this
thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084093/1031297

Add ['@nuxtjs/axios']....

Add or Modify **plugins/axios.js**

```
export default ({ app, $axios ,store }) => {      
  $axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    store.commit("SET_DATA", { data:true, id: "loading" });
    return config;
  }, (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  $axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    store.commit("SET_DATA", { data:false, id: "loading" });
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

**with the store being**

```
export default {
  state: () => ({
    loading: false
  }),
  mutations: {
    SET_DATA(state, { id, data }) {
      state[id] = data
    }
  },
  actions: {

  }
}
```

Comment: @vsync as I said, it's for nuxt users. if you're not a nuxt user, go dig somewhere else or diy

Comment: How would an axios request look like when adding those?